# Woocommerce White Screen

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I have updated Woocommerce to the latest version but now payments are no longer being processed on the frontend for both payment methods: BACS and SagePay. Once 'place order' is clicked it stays on the same page, no emails are received although the order does appear on the backend.

If I try and cancel the order it brings up a white screen.

I am using the latest version of Wordpress.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Edit - Please inspect element using Google Chrome, if you receive an Ajax error or 500-503 error then the paragraph below explains it.

What SagePay plugin are you using? If you are using the free direct gateway plugin. Then this plugin is no longer supported/updated therefore isn't working with WP 4.1.1. From my experience, if you disable the SagePay plugin your 'place order' button should now work again.